# How and where to upload/download a file with cmd.exe/PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp, webserver, http, powershell-2.0

I wanted to download files via CMD, and the first way I discovered was FTP. I rent a server and everything worked. The problem is that it takes kinda long to type in the credentials. After some research I found this PowerShell line:

```
powershell (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://website.com/file.exe','%TEMP%\file.exe')
```

But I have some questions:

What is the part after %TEMP% for? Is that the destination where the files "arrives"? So if i wanted to download it to C:\, I just have to change it to C:\, right?
Where can I host the file for free? I found some web server hosting sites, but the only databases I was able to find were FTP and MySQL.
Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: I know cmd.exe ftp command has ftp scripts.. and also you can download whatever file with wget, entering  `wget http://blah.com/myfile.txt`   wget can download files via ftp too.. but if there is a user/pass then it's a bit more long winded.. No doubt powershell has scripts too. As well as the scripting language so cmd.exe has batch and powershell would have its thing. The thing after %TEMP% looks like it is saving the file with that filename. (potentially renaming it) but in this case downloading file.exe and saving it to the directory %TEMP% with filename file.exe so same name

Comment: %TEMP%\file.exe is a path. Try entering `ECHO %TEMP%\asdfsdf.aaa` and you will see what in this case could be said to amount to a file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the part after %TEMP% for?

You can find that out by looking up the documentation of the .Net WebClient's DownloadFile method you're using:

[WebClient.DownloadFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Since you're invoking it with the arguments `'http://website.com/file.exe'` and `'%TEMP%\file.exe'`, which are two strings, then the specific invocation documentation is here:

[WebClient.DownloadFile Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx)

That page shows the expected parameters/arguments are `address` and `filename`:

```
address
    Type: System.String
    The URI from which to download data. 

fileName
    Type: System.String
    The name of the local file that is to receive the data.
```

So as you can see there, that `filename` argument is in fact "the destination where the files "arrives"".  Or more accurately, it's the file that's created and then filled with the data streamed from the FTP server via the web client.

Keep in mind that `%TEMP%` is a variable that represents the path to the Temp folder for your user (ie: `C:\Users\c0ntrix\AppData\Local\Temp`).

> So if i wanted to download it to C:\, I just have to change it to C:\, right?

As long as you also include an actual file name.  So you'd change `'%TEMP%\file.exe'` to `c:\file.txt`.

*Note:* In general, saving to the root of C: is a bad idea, and as such Windows will try to prevent it (by requiring Admin elevation, etc.), so aim for a folder instead.

> Where can I host the file for free?

You can setup your own FTP server at your house.  Beyond that, questions asking for service recommendations are considered off-topic for SU.  Just Google "free FTP hosts" and start searching, and/or speak with your ISP, as they may be willing to provide some FTP space as part of your monthly subscription.

> the only databases I was able to find were FTP and MySQL

FTP is not a database, it's the "File transfer Protocol", and it's used for transferring files, that's it.

Comment: thank you for this answer. As I already have a FTP Server. But i thought I could only access it with a FTP Client? If not, is the file just automatically on mysite.com/file.exe when it is in the root folder?